# An array that stores a dictionary. Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, uitableview, swift, dictionary

I am having a hard time trying to figure this out in swift. So I want to populate a table view that has all the station list search init and in each cell is the station name, stream bitrate and now playing. I dont have much experience with programing as well.

```
 "station_list": {
        "1": {
            "number": 1,
            "sid": "6235",
            "name": "WwW Radio",
            "streams": {
                "stream_format": "9",
                "stream_format_string": ".MP3/.M3U Playlist",
                "stream_bitrate": "5",
                "stream_bitrate_string": "128 kbps",
                "now_playing": "",
                "test_up": 0
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "number": 2,
            "sid": "25755",
            "name": "EKR - Rock Radio 24/7",
            "streams": {
                "stream_format": "9",
                "stream_format_string": ".MP3/.M3U Playlist",
                "stream_bitrate": "3",
                "stream_bitrate_string": "64 kbps",
                "now_playing": "",
                "test_up": 0
            }
        },
        "3": {
            "number": 3,
            "sid": "25965",
            "name": "Classic Rock Radio",
            "streams": {
                "stream_format": "9",
                "stream_format_string": ".MP3/.M3U Playlist",
                "stream_bitrate": "4",
                "stream_bitrate_string": "96 kbps",
                "now_playing": "",
                "test_up": 0
            }
        },
```

Comment: At a guess, it looks like you may be getting way ahead of yourself. It's good that you know that you need arrays and dictionaries. It's not so good that you don't yet now how to move this data into arrays and dictionaries. You may want to go back and learn more of the basics before embarking on this project. :)

Comment: You should state more clearly what you are trying to achieve. The data you have been posting seems to be JSON, if you are trying to parse it a quick google might lead to [this library](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), if you do not know what I mean by "parsing" you should google "parse JSON" first.

Answer (score 0):

@everyone else even if this is json, it is not valid json.

If i were you i would go at this in a more step by step approach like this.

1. Figure out how input data for table is formatted
2. find way to read data
3. find way to put data into structure
4. create a table.
5. populate table from structure

here is a bit of sample code in swift based on reading json then populating a tableview with it.

to read it in it really depends on what type of data you have, if it is json in the same format as the quakes example provided by apple, you can read it quick and dirty with

```
readdata()
{
var jsonObject : AnyObject!
var filepath = "\(tempDir)JsonFile.dat"
var error: NSError?

var datafilecheck = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
//Check if data file exists
if datafilecheck.fileExistsAtPath(filepath)
{
let jsonData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filepath, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!

//Check if json object it readable
if let object = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary {
    cou = object["main"]!.count
    println("number of items in object = \(cou)")


    for(var row=0; row < cou; row++)
    {


        // = object["main"]![row]!["Title:"]!! as String
        var number = object["main"]![row]!["number:"]!! as String
        var sid = object["main"]![row]!["sid:"]!! as String

        /*Read it into some type of structure or core data ect here */

    }

    MainTable.reloadData()
}
else {
    println("error")

}
}
else
{
    println("Json data file NOT JSON FILE == nil, from getdict function")
}
}
```

Note: that example has limited error checking and also needs to be read into something, if you might have errors in your input i would recommend using a pre made framework to read json

also you will need these 2 functions for your table or something similar.

```
//Set Table view number of rows
func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return datastruct.count

}


//Set Table view cell entries
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    let identifier = tableColumn.identifier
    var cellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(identifier, owner: self) as NSTableCellView
    if (row < datastruct.count)
    {
        if identifier == "number:"
        {

            cellView.textField!.stringValue = datastruct[row].title
        }

        if identifier == "sid:"
        {
            cellView.textField!.stringValue = datastruct[row].filePath

        }

        return cellView
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The example you showed is clearly JSON. I can't really understand exactly what it is that you're asking, but my guess is that you want to know how to store this very same data structure in an array of dictionaries.

What you actually have here is a dictionary of dictionaries, but I'm going to make a guess that the keys at the top level are really just array indices. So you'd have something like this:

```
[ [ "number" : 3, "sid" : "25965", "name" : "Classic Rock Radio", "streams" : [ "stream_format": "9" ] ] ]
```

and so on. However, this screams to be an array of [model objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ModelObject.html) instead.

I should also add that, if you have data already in JSON format, you can convert it to dictionaries and arrays using the methods of [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html). This will give you Objective-C's `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, which are closely related to, but a bit different from their Swift counterparts.